# upickle: serialize / deserialize into js.Array

Tags: scala, scala.js

I'm trying to serialize/deserialize the following case classes using upickle and ScalaJs:

```
case class Cell(var x: String)
case class Container(var cells: js.Array[Cell] = js.Array())
```

upickle 0.2.5 claims that it doesn't know how to handle js.Arrays, so I ended up doing this:

```
object Helper {
  implicit val jsArrayWriter = upickle.Writer[js.Array[Cell]] {
    case array ⇒ writeJs(array: mutable.Seq[Cell])
  }

  implicit val jsArrayReader: Reader[js.Array[Cell]] = upickle.Reader[js.Array[Cell]] {
    case jsValue ⇒ readJs[mutable.Seq[Cell]](jsValue).toJSArray
  }
}
```

Is this the best way to handle js.Arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's reasonable. You can probably make it more-optimal using `upickle.json.{read/write}`. If you have time send a PR for `Reader/Writer[js.Value]` and we can put it into trunk.